# Javascript MVC: reset view to default state

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have a view which changes style and shows/hides elements in response to user actions. How can I return the view to its default state?

For example:

```js
class Model {
    constructor() {}
}

class Controller {
    constructor(model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    respondToButton() {
        $('#context-box').css('color', 'red');
        alert("Cannot do baz.");
    }

    respondToSelect(e) {
        if ($(e.target).val() == "foo") {
            $('#context-area').hide();
        } else {
            $('#context-area').show();
        }
    }
}

class View {
    constructor(controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    bindEvents() {
        $('#button').on('click', this.controller.respondToButton);
        $('#select').on('change', this.controller.respondToSelect);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select id="select">
        <option value="foo">Foo</option>
        <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    </select>

    <div hidden id="context-area">
        <span id="context-box">Baz</span>
        <button id="button">Do Baz?</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var model = new Model();
        var controller = new Controller(model);
        var view = new View(controller);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Once *context-box* has been modified, it remains this way even if the outer context changes. I would like it to return to its original 'on-load' state.

One option would be to just reload the page, but reloading the page in response to a select change doesn't feel very nice and would probably require an 'Are you sure?' unload event.

For this small example I could just reset the css in the select change event, but as *context-area* gets more complex the number of elements to reset grows. This also makes future changes frustrating, as every change also requires a corresponding reset.

The option I am currently using is to clone *context-area* on page load and then delete and restore the node in response to context changing. This works okay, but I find myself deleting and restoring the node in response to every model change just in case it is needed.

Is there a better way to handle this? How is this done in MVC frameworks (I haven't learned any yet)?

Comment: Which event in your example would need to reset the state?

Comment: respondToSelect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several schools of thought on MVC, so what follows will be a matter of opinion. I would inverse the connection between the View and the Controller, so that only the Controller is aware of the other two components. Possibly the Model should also be aware of the View, but since your example has no use case for that, I will ignore it.

I also feel that jQuery should be used in the View only, and not in the Controller: jQuery's role is to (easily) interact with the DOM, which is the role of the View.

For your particular question, I would implement a method `reset` in the View class, which the other components could call when appropriate. The View class would also call it itself in the constructor:

```js
class Model {
    constructor() {}
}

class Controller {
    constructor(model, view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        view.onButton(this.processAction.bind(this));
        view.onSelect(this.processChoice.bind(this));
    }

    processAction() {
        this.view.highlight = true;
        this.view.message("Cannot do baz.");
    }

    processChoice(value) {
        if (value === "foo") {
            this.view.reset();
        } else {
            this.view.showContext = true;
        }
    }
}

class View {
    constructor() {
        this.reset();
    }
    
    reset() {
        this.highlight = false;
        this.showContext = false;
    }
    
    onButton(listener) {
        $('#button').on('click', listener);
    }
    
    onSelect(listener) {
        $('#select').on('change', function (e) {
            listener($(e.target).val());
        });
    }
    
    set highlight(highlighted) {
        $('#context-box').css('color', highlighted ? 'red' : 'initial');
    }
    
    set showContext(visibility) {
        $('#context-area').toggle(visibility);
    }
    
    message(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
}

$(function() {
    new Controller(new Model(), new View());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>

<div hidden id="context-area">
    <span id="context-box">Baz</span>
    <button id="button">Do Baz?</button>
</div>
```

To take it a bit further, the View should really be made responsible for the initial HTML, meaning that you would start out with an empty page and the View instance would populate it:

```js
class Model {
    constructor() {}
}

class Controller {
    constructor(model, view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
        view.onButton(this.processAction.bind(this));
        view.onSelect(this.processChoice.bind(this));
    }

    processAction() {
        this.view.highlight = true;
        this.view.message("Cannot do baz.");
    }

    processChoice(value) {
        if (value === "foo") {
            this.view.reset();
        } else {
            this.view.showContext = true;
        }
    }
}

class View {
    constructor() {
        this.reset();
    }
    
    reset() {
        $(() => $("body").empty().append(
            this.$select = $("<select>").append(
                $("<option>").val("foo").text("Foo"),            
                $("<option>").val("bar").text("Bar")
            ),
            this.$contextArea = $("<div>").append(
                 this.$contextBox = $("<span>").text("Baz"),
                 this.$button = $("<button>").text("Do Baz?")
            ).hide()
        ));
    }
    
    onButton(listener) {
        $(() => $(document).on("click", e => 
            this.$button.is(e.target) && listener()
        ));
    }
    
    onSelect(listener) {
        $(() => $(document).on("change", e => 
            this.$select.is(e.target) && listener(this.$select.val())
        ));
    }
    
    set highlight(highlighted) {
        $(() => this.$contextBox.css('color', highlighted ? 'red' : 'initial'));
    }
    
    set showContext(visibility) {
        $(() => this.$contextArea.toggle(visibility));
    }
    
    message(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
}

new Controller(new Model(), new View());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In a server-driven web application, the MVC components would exist on the server side and you would use the capabilities of generating HTML offered by such server technology.

Comment: Good points on the V-C connection and use of jQuery. In my real project I set the view up as an observer to the model, so it is aware of the view in that sense.
I did try extending the 'just reset every change' option to use a dedicated reset function, which is certainly an improvement but still requires every change to have a corresponding line in reset.
Why does view call reset itself? Isn't this redundant since when the view is created it is already in the reset state?

Comment: Well, to be honest, you already had some initialisation in the HTML by using `hidden`. This kind of thing should really be done by the View upon initialisation. In a more extreme interpretation, it should be the View that generates the HTML in the first place. So you would start with no HTML elements in the `body`. That would be populated when the View is constructed. So in that scenario it really makes sense that the `reset` is called in the constructor. That `reset` could in fact empty the `body` tag and repopulate it.

Comment: I added an implementation of what I said above.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the classic way to do is to send ajax request to get the page again and to refresh only the part you want using the html you will get as a response.

But your idea to save a node on load and then to restore it whenever you want seems to be the fastest !

**EDIT :** For Ajax request I was thinking about something like that :

```js
function resetDiv() {
  let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.open('GET', "YOUR DEFAULT PAGE PATH");
  myRequest.responseType = "document";
  myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { 
      if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
         let doc = myRequest.response;
          document.getElementById('context-area').innerHTML = doc.getElementById('context-area').innerHTML;
      }
  };
  myRequest.send();
}

function showContext(element) {
 if(element.value == "bar") {
   $('#context-area').show();
  } else {
   $('#context-area').hide();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" onchange="showContext(this);">
    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
<div hidden id="context-area">
    <span id="context-box">Baz</span>
</div>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetDiv();">
reset
</button>
```

Comment: Could you expand on refreshing only the part I want? How would I extract the context-area node in my example from the retrieved html? I could load the html into a DOM object and then parse out the node I want, but that seems like just storing the node itself with additional overhead from ajax.